# How to set a timeout on WinHttpWebSocketReceive

Tags: winapi, winhttp

Is there a way to set a receive timeout on (synchronous) calls to [WinHttpWebSocketReceive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winhttp/nf-winhttp-winhttpwebsocketreceive)?
I've tried [WinHttpSetTimeouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winhttp/nf-winhttp-winhttpsettimeouts) but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I believe `WinHttpSetTimeouts()` only works for HTTP.  Although WebSocket does use HTTP for the initial handshake, once the connection is operating in full WebSocket mode then HTTP timeouts no longer apply.

Comment: Use WinHTTP APIs with timeout options. After [upgrading from http to websocket](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/7cbd99ac1d2b4a0beffbaba29ea63d024ceff700/Samples/WinhttpWebsocket/cpp/WinhttpWebsocket.cpp#L76), It's unknown if timeout options work.